Google Chat webhook with Paypal Braintree Gateway
Has anyone tried to set up a webhook from Braintree into Google Chat? Braintree have an API section of their website where you can put the URL of a webhook in, and you should get notifications when actions occur on the platform.
I set up a Space on Chat, and created the webhook and pasted this URL from Chat into Braintree. However, whenever I test the integration on Braintree it returns an error. I got in touch with their support team, and they've said it's a Google fault, not theirs.
So, I thought I'd check if anyone else had tried this integration.
Thanks!



My aim is to get a notification to the Google Chat space when a dispute gets raised in Braintree, simply to alert us that it has happened
